# I need an excel macro to export data based on variable

Tags: excel, csv, export, vba

I have a spreadsheet that exports saved invoices.  the export works perfectly.  however, i want to ONLY export data for the previous week.  the last cell in the workbook has the last saved date in it.  i want to search through the column to find the last saved date within the previous 7 days, and create an export csv file with just that data.

here is what i have so far.

```
Sub CopyToCSV()
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFileName As String
Dim Region As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Invoice").Activate
Region = Range("E5").Value
Sheets("Stored Invoices").Activate

MyPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
MyFileName = "Region" & Region & "-" & Format(Date, "ddmmyy")
'Makes sure the path name ends with "\":
MyPath = MyPath & "\"
'Makes sure the filename ends with ".csv"
MyFileName = MyFileName & ".csv"
'Copies the sheet to a new workbook:
Sheets("Stored Invoices").Copy
'The new workbook becomes Activeworkbook:
With ActiveWorkbook
'Saves the new workbook to given folder / filename:
'MyPath &
.SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
'Closes the file
.Close False
End With
End Sub
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Becky

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is in order:

Loop through each cell in the column containing the date, and evaluate said date. Have it loop until it encounters a date more than 7 days before the current data. Have a counter in the loop that counts how many rows it looped though. then, its simply `Range("A1", Cells(countedrows, Numcolumns)).copy DestinationRange` assuming the data starts in a1, so the range would be from A1 down to the last counted row in the last column, and then you move that to a new Sheet/book, and save that

there be the logic, Edit your post with your new code and comment if you get stuck

HTH